# Limit on clearing session storage through out a test suite in Protractor?

Tags: protractor

I have a test suite that accesses a URL multiple times and needs to complete a user registration. The individual specs all use the following to clear the session

`afterAll(function() {
        browser.executeScript('window.sessionStorage.clear();'); 
        browser.executeScript('window.localStorage.clear();'); 
    });`

The issue is the third time the URL is clicked, it still has the information from the previous registration and thinks that the registration is completed. Is there a limit to clearing sessions and/or is there a better practice to clearing session storage?

Comment: Be aware that `window.localStorage.clear();` clears the data for the current domain only. So the storage will remain untouched if the third URL leads to another domain. If it's the case, you'll have to call `get` beforehand. It could also be that the storage is rebuilt from the cookies. So make sure to clear them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `afterAll()` code is executed after all the tests have run at the end of the test-suite. If you want to cleanup after tests you should use `afterEach()` instead. Protractor uses Jasmine, check [the documentation about Setup and TearDowns](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Setup_and_Teardown).

The clear Storage functions do not clear the cookies, only the storage used by the developers. Often session information is stored in cookies instead. You could try to also clear the cookies after each test with `browser.manage().deleteAllCookies()` or use `browser.restart()` to start with a fresh session.

Also, see [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40296093/protractor-clear-browsing-data-completely)